# Internet Explorer - Unexpected character in comment end warning

Tags: html, internet-explorer, comments, warnings

Internet Explorer complains about the **two dashes** in the url **inside of a comment**:

```
<!--
<iframe src="/file.php?var=AQJ--dsf"></iframe>
-->
```

> HTML1416: Unexpected character in comment end. Expected "-->".

How do I get rid of this ridiculous error message?

Comment: You cannot have `--` (two hypens) inside a comment (AQJ--dsf)

Answer (score 8):

From [the HTML 5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#comments):

> Comments must start with the four character sequence U+003C LESS-THAN SIGN, U+0021 EXCLAMATION MARK, U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS, U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS (`<!--`). Following this sequence, the comment may have text, with the additional restriction that the text must not start with a single "`>`" (U+003E) character, nor start with a U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS character (-) followed by a "`>`" (U+003E) character, **nor contain two consecutive U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS characters (`--`)**, nor end with a U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS character (`-`). Finally, the comment must be ended by the three character sequence U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS, U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS, U+003E GREATER-THAN SIGN (`-->`).

To get rid of the error message. Stop making the error. Rewrite the part of the code with `--` inside the comment.

Comment: lol. It's not me who is making the error. The dashes are in an external url.

Comment: @reggie — Which you have expressed in HTML and put inside a comment where it isn't allowed.

Answer (score 0):

As quoted from wr.org

"A common error is to include a string of hyphens ("---") within a comment. Authors should avoid putting two or more adjacent hyphens inside comments."

Link [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.4)

Answer (score 0):

The HTML 5 spec regarding comments no longer prohibits '--' between the start-/end-comment markers.

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#comments

HTML -- Living Standard — Last Updated 28 January 2023

13.1.6 Comments

Comments must have the following format:

1. The string "<!--".
2. Optionally, text, with the additional restriction that the text must

   -- not start with the string ">",

   -- nor start with the string "->",

   -- nor contain the strings "", or "--!>",

   -- nor end with the string "<!-".
3. The string "-->".

[note:] The text is allowed to end with the string "<!", as in  and .